# How do I copy a specific booking resource on the WooCommerce Bookings order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

Upon completion of the WooCommerce Bookings order I'd like to CC the resource (post type `bookable_resource`) that was assigned/selected/associated with the order. Then repeat the CC during the booking reminder. I've tried a hand-full of ideas but the code below (obviously incorrect) is where I stopped at.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

```
function cc_resource_order( $headers, $email_id, $order) {
    
    if ( 'customer_completed_order' == $email_id) {
        $headers .= "Bcc: Name <this-works@thedomain.com>\r\n";
        $headers .= "Cc: Name <this-works-too@anotherdomain.com>\r\n";
    
        if (( 'bookable_resource' == get_post_type() ) && (get_the_ID() == 123456)){
            $headers .= "Cc: Name <this-doesnt-work@samedomain.com>\r\n";
        }
        elseif (( 'bookable_resource' == get_post_type() ) && (get_the_ID() == 654321)){
            $headers .= "Cc: Name <this-too-doesnt-work@samedomain.com>\r\n";
        }               
    }
    return $headers;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'cc_resource_order', 9999, 3 );
```

```
function cc_resource_reminder( $headers, $email_id, $order) {
    
    if ( 'booking_reminder' == $email_id) {
        $headers .= "Bcc: Name <this-works@thedomain.com>\r\n";
        $headers .= "Cc: Name <this-works-too@anotherdomain.com>\r\n";
    
        if (( 'bookable_resource' == get_post_type() ) && (get_the_ID() == 123456)){
            $headers .= "Cc: Name <this-doesnt-work@samedomain.com>\r\n";
        }
        elseif (( 'bookable_resource' == get_post_type() ) && (get_the_ID() == 654321)){
            $headers .= "Cc: Name <nope-here-too@samedomain.com>\r\n";
        }               
    }
    return $headers;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'cc_resource_reminder', 9999, 3 );
```